# Change Background Color specific QSplitter Child

Tags: c++, qt, qsplitter

I am using Qt Creator 4.13.1 with Qt 5.15.1 on Windows 10 Pro.

I am new to using Stylesheets in Qt and a bit confused of the possible selectors considering `QSplitter` and its child. I want to have 2 childs separated by a splitter-handle and draw their backgrounds in different colors.

This is an example szenario

```cpp
QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter();

QWidget* widgetA = new QWidget();
// add a layout with some further child widgets
QWidget* widgetB = new QWidget();
// add a layout with some further child widgets

splitter->addWidget(widgetA);
splitter->addWidget(widgetB);

layout()->addWidget(splitter);
```

where I tried:

- `widgetA->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ff0000;");` which applies to all child widgets of `widgetA` (e.g. QLabels, QPushButtons, ...) , but not to their surrounding `widgetA` itself
- `splitter->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ff0000;");` applies to the `widgetA`, `widgetB` and the handle and all widgets below `widgetA` and `widgetB`
- naming `widgetA->setObjectName("Tim");` and `splitter->setStyleSheet("QWidget#Tim {background-color: #ff0000;}");` which has no effect at all.
- **[EDIT]** `splitter->setStyleSheet("QSplitter QWidget #Andy {background-color: #ff0000;}");` applies the background only to a certain widget inside either child widget. But using `splitter->setStyleSheet("QSplitter #Tim {background-color: #ff0000;}");` has (again) no effect at all.

**How would I set the `background-color` of `widgetA` separately, so without affecting the childs of `widgetA` or the other splitter child `widgetB`?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  If you want `widgetA` to have a certain style sheet then you call `widgetA->setStyleSheet(...)` -- it doesn't really have anything to do with the splitter.

Comment: `widgetA->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ff0000;");` should set the color for the container as well. I also tested it just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with using `widget->setStyleSheet()` in your case. Here, I have tested your implementation of `setObjectName()`:

```
Application::Application(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    //set a base layout for the parent of splitter
    QHBoxLayout *boxLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    this->setLayout(boxLayout);
    //allocate splitter with parent
    QSplitter* splitter = new QSplitter(this);

    QWidget* widgetA = new QWidget();
    widgetA->setObjectName("widgetA");
    widgetA->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    //example buttons as child for widgetA
    QPushButton *p = new QPushButton("0",widgetA);
    widgetA->layout()->addWidget(p);
    p = new QPushButton("1",widgetA);
    widgetA->layout()->addWidget(p);
    p = new QPushButton("2",widgetA);
    widgetA->layout()->addWidget(p);
    p = new QPushButton("3",widgetA);
    widgetA->layout()->addWidget(p);
    //widgetB, all similar to widgetA
    QWidget* widgetB = new QWidget();
    widgetB->setObjectName("widgetB");
    widgetB->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    widgetA->setStyleSheet("QWidget#widgetA{background-color: #ff0000;}");
    widgetB->setStyleSheet("QWidget#widgetB{background-color: #00ff00;}");
    p = new QPushButton("1",widgetB);
    widgetB->layout()->addWidget(p);
    p = new QPushButton("2",widgetB);
    widgetB->layout()->addWidget(p);
    p = new QPushButton("3",widgetB);
    widgetB->layout()->addWidget(p);
    
    //add both widgets to splitter
    splitter->addWidget(widgetA);
    splitter->addWidget(widgetB);

    //add splitter to base layout
    this->layout()->addWidget(splitter);
}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: hmm thats weird, looks like the way I tried it... I will have a closer look at this tomorrow. Thanks by now.